# iPhone; Continuously Get Video from Camera

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

First of all I have to admit that I haven't upgraded to SDK 3.1 yet. AFAIK, there is possibility to record video using SDK, but again popping up camera and allowing user to start/stop recording and save the recorded Video. First, is this correct?

Now, my question; Is it possible to get video stream from Iphone? I just want to trigger it from code, get frames, and use them in my program.

My question does not include jailbroken/toolchain solutions, I'm asking if it's possible in Apple's SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an undocumented API call...so its possible, but not legal. Your app may not make it into the app-store - especially as Apple now use static code analysis in order to automagically spot undocumented API calls.

There have been "reference cases" of people using these calls - the AR browser apps for instance, but they were generally submitted before the switch to static code analysis.  There is also one test case of a letter to Steve Jobs getting an app in that used one of these API calls, but I its certainly not legal with the current SDK.

Edit: 
The nice people here http://gamesalfresco.com/2009/10/16/ismar-2009-sketch-and-shape-recognition-preview-from-ben-gurion-university/ will email you a sample app with live video - you just need to ask. Note - it is only the video code they will send you - not the AR demos shown.

Comment: can it be directly used without toolchain?

Comment: I think so - you just have to know what the calls are (which I don't currently). The test case I mentioned is here http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2009/12/steve-jobs-intervenes-approves-knocking-streaming-video-app.ars